# Flicker when moving views at runtime

Tags: android, rendering, android-relativelayout

I have an ImageView and 3 TextViews inside a relative layout, and need to position the text views at run time depending on the size of the image.  At the moment I'm using a ViewTreeObserver on the image so that I can use it's width/height to position the text boxes.

Everything works fine except that the TextViews jump to the correct location on load, making it appear like there's a flicker.

Is there a way to reposition the TextViews before the screen renders but once the ImageView has it's width and height set?

Here's a (simplified) version of the XML code:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutMain"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/myImage"
        android:src="@drawable/myImageSrc"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="..."
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/myImage"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/myImage"/>    
</RelativeLayout>
```

And here's the code I'm using in the addOnGlobalLayoutListener callback to position the text view at run time:

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayoutMain);

RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
int width = relativeLayout.getMeasuredWidth();
int height = relativeLayout.getMeasuredHeight();

TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
int w = tv.getMeasuredWidth();
int h = tv.getMeasuredHeight();
layoutParams.setMargins((int) (width * 0.5 - w / 2), (int) (height * 0.54 - h / 2), 0, 0);
tv.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: Yes there is ! in xml layout. You can do this easily in your xml. Just post your layout xml code so I can help.

Comment: I suspect that you just want your `TextView`s to may be always below or above the `ImageView`. If that's the case then it can be done in xml but if there is something like placing `TextView` to place A for x size but for a size y place B which is totally different, then it needs to be done at run-time.

Comment: It needs to be the latter.  The position is dependent on the size of the ImageView which is only known at runtime.  I did think about hiding the TextView s until they're in the correct position - that would at least mean they don't jump location.

Comment: Believe me it doesn't matter as long as you are not jumping around for different sizes. Just post your xml and tell me precisely what you want. you want your `TextView` to be on left, right, bottom or top of `ImageView` as long as this constraint doesn't change you don't need to do it at run time. You can load any size at run-time and UI will not break. But if you still insist on doing it then may be consider using nineoldandorid animation framework.

Comment: Extra details added above.  If it's achievable in XML only then I'd much rather do it that way!

Comment: So you want your `TextView` to be almost at the center of `ImageView`? right ?

Comment: This particular one yes.  But there are others that I position at specific percentages into the image.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want your `TextView` at the center of `ImageView`. Here is how you can achieve it, You can add margin to your `TextView` to tweak its position now.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutMain"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/myImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitStart"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myTextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" 
    android:text="..." />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: That particular element wants to be in the center, but others need to appear elsewhere in the image.  At the moment in the code, I'm placing them at certain percentages of the width and height.

Comment: well then best approach is to extend `RelativeLayout` and override `onMeasure` method and after calling super assign proper positions to childs. or easy way is just to hide them until you position them properly. First approach would be easy for you if you have experience with custom views.